# How to Delete Rows That Contains both have Space and Non-space in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where I want to drop some rows in my that contain some text.

```
Date      Description
8/15/23   QRCODE from store X
8/15/23   QR CODE from store XY
8/15/23   QR CODE from store X
8/15/23   QRCODE from store X
8/15/23   Transfer from store A
8/15/23   Transfer from store A
8/15/23   Payment from store Z
8/15/23   Payment from store Z
8/15/23   Transfer from store A
8/15/23   ...
```

I want to delete all rows contains "QR CODE". The problem is it have both "QR CODE" and "QRCODE".

I have try:

```
words = ["QR CODE", "QRCODE"]
mask = df.Description.str.contains(r'\b(?:{})\b'.format('|'.join(words)))
df = df[~mask]
```

But it take a lot of times to type all words I need, for example: "Wallmart" and "Wall mart" | "eBay" and "e Bay" | "Best buy" and "Bestbuy"....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['8/15/23', 'QRCODE from store X'],
    ['8/15/23', 'QR CODE from store XY'],
    ['8/15/23', 'QR CODE from store X'],
    ['8/15/23', 'QRCODE from store X'],
    ['8/15/23', 'Transfer from store A'],
    ['8/15/23', 'Transfer from store A'],
    ['8/15/23', 'Payment from store Z'],
    ['8/15/23', 'Payment from store Z'],
    ['8/15/23', 'Transfer from store A']
], columns=['Date', 'Description'])

# put the search terms in here
search_terms = ["Wall mart", "e Bay", "Best buy", "QR CODE"]

# replace all spaces with ' ?', and make them all lowercase
search_terms = [r'\b' + re.sub(r'\s+', ' ?', term).lower() + r'\b' for term in search_terms]

# concatenate with vertical pipes (meaning match any of them)
search_terms = '|'.join(search_terms)

# filter rows to ones where the description lowercase doesn't match search_terms
df[~df['Description'].str.lower().str.contains(search_terms)]
      Date            Description
4  8/15/23  Transfer from store A
5  8/15/23  Transfer from store A
6  8/15/23   Payment from store Z
7  8/15/23   Payment from store Z
8  8/15/23  Transfer from store A
```

I made it so that it matches regardless of case, but this might not be what you want- let me know! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can add replaced words with space to list `words`:

```
words = ["QR CODE"]

words += [x.replace(' ', '') for x in words]

mask = df.Description.str.contains(r'\b(?:{})\b'.format('|'.join(words)), case=False)
df = df[~mask]
print (df)
      Date            Description
4  8/15/23  Transfer from store A
5  8/15/23  Transfer from store A
6  8/15/23   Payment from store Z
7  8/15/23   Payment from store Z
8  8/15/23  Transfer from store A
```

Comment: @Mark - need word bondaries I think.

Comment: yup, just added them :-)

Comment: btw @jezrael it seems like the code in your profile doesn't work :P Maybe a pandas syntax change? The last line works with `print (pd.DataFrame(d).pivot(index=1, columns=0, values=2).applymap(chr).agg(''.join))` for me

Comment: @Mark - thank you, I can check it.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't try to match both `QRCODE` and `QR CODE` separately, this is inefficient, rather define the list with spaces and make the spaces optional:

```
words = ["QR CODE", "Wall Markt"]
words2 = [w.replace(' ', ' ?') for w in words]
# ['QR ?CODE', 'Wall ?Markt']

mask = df.Description.str.contains(r'\b(?:{})\b'.format('|'.join(words2)))
df = df[~mask]
```

Output:

```
      Date            Description
4  8/15/23  Transfer from store A
5  8/15/23  Transfer from store A
6  8/15/23   Payment from store Z
7  8/15/23   Payment from store Z
8  8/15/23  Transfer from store A
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you want to generalize the concept to the words with spaces, not just QRCode, wallmart, eBay and BestBuy.
The first part would be detecting words which have spaces. From your shown format, we can take a part of string which is before `' from'`.

```
df_space = df.loc[df['Description'].map(lambda st: True if st[:st.find(' from')].count(' ') > 0 else False)]
```

This will give the part of dataframe where there are spaces before `' from'`
After that you can decide to either drop those rows with:

```
df = df.drop(df_space.index)      or     df.drop(df_space.index, inplace=True)
```

or replace the spaces:

```
df['Description'] = df['Description'].map(lambda st: st[:st.find(' from')].replace(' ', '') + st[st.find(' from'):])
```

Comment: Your `map` is a very inefficient way to do `df['Description'].str.extract(r'(.*) from\b')`